# Eclipse Decorators update very slow (3.7.1)

Tags: eclipse

since the update to Eclipse 3.7.1 the error/warning decorations disappear very slow. I might add, that I have 398 java plug-in projects in my workspace.
When I encounter a compile error in a file, fix it, it takes about several seconds (3-15) until the decoration is cleared. 
Does anyone have an idea where this comes from or encountered it too?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 398 projects in a single workspace?! What's your memory settings? Ever consider not having that many projects in your workspace?

Comment: I've noticed same problem and I've a clean fresh Windows 7 installation with Eclipse 3.7 and only two Android project.
Another colleague said he experienced the same!

Comment: @Dave: you are absolutely right: We have to reduce the amount. Using Target-Platforms for instance. But that requires a higher degree of modularization for us. To achieve that, we need to change a lot (what we are currently doing). So, as long as we don't have that required granularity we need all the plug-ins in one workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the solution yet, but at least found some aspects, which are improving the overall situation:

1. "Disable font and color decorations" in the SVN Decorator Settings.
2. Switching from subversive to subclipse
3. Reducing the amount of open plugins by closing the projects.